# Lean Kanban without estimates or time logging

Tags: scrum, estimation, kanban, lean

I work in academia (research). Tasks are varied and almost always involve delving into topics that produce more tasks when you are more informed. A pull system seems appropriate rather than an estimated timed-box scrum.

My question is then - is time-logging *really* recommended? Projects are so varied, that I would not be comfortable looking at a few previous projects and saying "this new project would take the same as these previous projects". The goal for us is to be as lean and flexible as possible to have a high-level visualization of each project to know where we are with each at a glance. If new projects come in, we'll have an hour meeting to discuss it and use our experience to give an overall estimate of when we can deliver the project.

Answer (score 2):

If you see little value from estimating project duration then don't bother with it.

However, there may be some value in measuring the time it takes for tasks to pass through the workflow. One of the Kanban principles is to look at cycle time and use it to help analyse process improvements.

For example, you might try and put a work in progress limit on one particular stage of the work flow and you can check the cycle times to see if this has made things better or worse.

Comment: +1 for focus on WiP instead of efforts logged.